# user email not returned through firebase yahoo after a successful login

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, authentication

I am trying to implement yahoo login using firebase in my project, the user can log in but in success function, uid is generated but user email is empty. Other social network like google, facebook twitter are working using firebase

this is the javascript code for login

```
var providerYh = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('yahoo.com');

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(providerYh)
            .then(function (result) {
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                var user = result.user;
                //user.email is empty
});
```

[yahoo developer settings screenshot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBJTO.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: We can't help you in any way without you showing us the relevant code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi i edited my post please see the code

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. When an app is created in developer.yahoo console app configuration should be like this in the screenshot

[app configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGMs4.png)